# Why does List[Int].apply(1,2,3) give an error in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, coming from python and trying to wrap my head around some of the syntax and conventions. I'm curious why the following doesn't work:

```
scala> val tmp = List[Int].apply(1,2,3)
<console>:7: error: missing arguments for method apply in object List;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
    val tmp = List[Int].apply(1,2,3)
```

Yet, when I do the following, I get no error:

```
scala> val tmp = List.apply(1,2,3)
tmp: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)

scala> val tmp = List[Int](1,2,3)
tmp: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
```

Why does `List[Int].apply()` give me an error?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because your syntax is wrong.  If you want the equivalent of `List.apply(1,2,3)`, then it should be:

```
val tmp = List.apply[Int](1,2,3)
```

In the expression `List.apply(1,2,3)`, `List` is referencing the companion object, and objects can't have generics.  Thus, you have to put the generic on the method.

For reference, you can see this in the source code for `List`:

```
object List extends SeqFactory[List] {
  ...
  override def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = xs.toList
```

When you write `List[Int].apply(1,2,3)`, Scala interprets that as `(List[Int]).apply(1,2,3)`.  And `List[Int]` is interpreted as if it were `List[Int]()` without the parentheses, which is equivalent to `List.apply[Int]`.  Since `apply` requires an argument, Scala gives you an error telling you that it's missing.